# Why is Jest Failing Tests for Missing Unique Keys?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have several tests that are failing due to this error:

> **Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.%s%s*

I am aware of the React `key` requirement - I had added keys to the `<li />` elements (everywhere I *thought* needed them), but that wasn't working:

> Error: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop
>
> (this error is WITH a key on the list items ???)

...so I went nuts adding keys and running the test and *eventually* put a key on every HTML element:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { constants, ProductStatusInfo, Tooltip } from 'trucktrax-common';
import { AGGREGATE_STRING, CEMENT_STRING, READYMIX_VALUE } from '../../../constants/appConstants';
import styles from './LegendMapKey.module.scss';

export class LegendMapKey extends Component<LegendMapKeyProps> {
  bySequenceNumber = (a: ProductStatusInfo, b: ProductStatusInfo) => a.sequenceNumber - b.sequenceNumber;

  productStatusInfoToListItem = (psi: ProductStatusInfo, index: number): JSX.Element => this.renderListItem(psi, index);

  productStatusInfosToListItems = (psiList: ProductStatusInfo[]) => Object.values(psiList)
    .sort(this.bySequenceNumber) // musn't forget to sort them
    // this list is static, and will not change, so using an index is fine
    .map(this.productStatusInfoToListItem);

  renderListItem = (psi: ProductStatusInfo, key: number) => (
    // what a very nice key for every list item
    <li key={key} className={styles.statusKey}>
      <Tooltip
        key={`tt${key}`}
        theme="info"
        text={psi.name}
        classes={{
          popper: styles.popper,
          tooltip: styles.tooltip
        }}
      >
        <span key={`span${key}`}>
          <i key={`dot${key}`} className="icon-dot" style={{ color: psi.color }} />
          {psi.abbreviation}
        </span>
      </Tooltip>
    </li>
  )

  renderProductStatusList = (key: string, title: string, psiList: ProductStatusInfo[]) => {
    const list = this.productStatusInfosToListItems(psiList);
    return (
      <div key={key} className={styles.productColumn}>
        <div key={`title${key}`} className={styles.title}>{title}</div>
        <ul key={`ul${key}`}>{list}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  };

  renderMapStateKeys = () => {
    const emptyElement = (< ></>);
    const { productLines } = this.props;
    const { aggregateStatuses, cementStatuses, readyMixStatuses } = constants.PRODUCT_STATUSES;
    const aggregate = productLines.includes(AGGREGATE_STRING)
      ? this.renderProductStatusList('LegendAgg', 'Aggr.', aggregateStatuses) : emptyElement;
    const cement = productLines.includes(CEMENT_STRING)
      ? this.renderProductStatusList('LegendCement', 'Cement', cementStatuses) : emptyElement;
    const readyMix = productLines.includes(READYMIX_VALUE)
      ? this.renderProductStatusList('LegendRMix', 'R.Mix', readyMixStatuses) : emptyElement;

    // they need to be in this order in the legend
    return [aggregate, cement, readyMix];
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div key="legend" className={styles.legend}>
        {this.renderMapStateKeys()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LegendMapKey;

export interface LegendMapKeyProps {
  productLines: string[];
}
```

...this code runs as expected without errors, but nevertheless, I am faced with a failing test, the above error message, and this gem when I debug the test:

> console.error src/setupTests.ts:25
>
> Check the top-level render call using <div>.
> in Fragment

An example of a failing test:

```
  it('should render with Aggregates Only', () => {
    const testProps = {
      productLines: ['Aggregates']
    };
    const wrapper2 = shallow(<LegendMapKey {...testProps} />);
    expect(wrapper2.length)
      .toEqual(1);
  });
```

Comment: You only need keys on the root of mapped arrays.

Comment: Specifically, just the `<li key={key}` key, which should be an index and looks correct (other than the fact that indices are not good keys--maybe `psi.name` is unique?). Remove everything else. Minimizing the code is a good way to solve problems like this. Remove everything until the error disappears, then re-introduce the last piece you removed--there's the problem (in most cases). See [mcve]. I assume you're using [tag:enzyme] here?

Comment: _I started out with no keys at all_ - then I added them to the `<li />` and it still didn't work.  I kept adding keys (because the debug message mentioned a `<div>`) - and the test still fails.

Comment: Did you strip it down to just the `<li>`s and you've logged those keys to confirm they're in fact unique indices as you expect? Just because you have `key=` doesn't mean the keys you've added are unique, so you can still get the error. Possibly the `return [aggregate, cement, readyMix];` is the next thing to look at. If you _remove_ the `<li>`s completely and the problem persists, then that array may be the problem. Strategically adding/removing parts of the tree to minimize/localize should be the way to isolate the problem rather than trying to add keys on everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When debugging problems like this, the best approach is to simplify code down to a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

> The more code there is to go through, the less likely people can find your problem. Streamline your example in one of two ways:
>
> **Restart from scratch**. Create a new program, adding in only what is needed to see the problem. Use simple, descriptive names for functions and variables – don’t copy the names you’re using in your existing code.
>
> **Divide and conquer**. If you're not sure what the source of the problem is, start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears – then add the last part back.

Here's the failing pattern in your code, which I identified by restarting from scratch with what I hypothesized might be the problem (I could also have used a D&C approach):

```js
const Example = () => {
  const empty = <React.Fragment />;
  return <div>{[empty, empty]}</div>;
};
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<Example />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

If the output isn't visible, I get:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Example`.
```

This fails too:

```js
const Example = () => <div>{[<React.Fragment />, <React.Fragment />]}</div>;
```

Since you're rendering an array returned by `this.renderMapStateKeys()`, you'll need to add a key to each of those elements, regardless of whether they're empty fragments or not:

```js
const Example = () => {
  const empty = () => <React.Fragment key={crypto.randomUUID()} />;
  return <div>{[empty(), empty()]}</div>;
};
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<Example />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

As you can see, you'll need to have separate fragment objects for each placeholder, or find a way to filter the array so that only the non-empty sections are in it.